# Reference relationships in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I’m new to studying the backend and MongoDB in particular, so I’ll try to explain as simply as possible what I mean.

I have 2 models, project and user.

**UserModel:**

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  git: {
    type: String,
  },
  tags: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  about: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  socials: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  projects: {
    type: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Project",
      },
    ],
    default: [],
  },
  avatarUrl: {
    type: String,
  },
});

export default mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

**ProjectModel:**

```
const projectSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  tags: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  needs: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  socials: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
});
```

They have links to each other, the project has a link to whoever created it, and the user has a link to all of his projects.

I also have the following functionality for creating an project:

```
export const create = async (req: AuthRequest, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const { title, tags, text, needs, socials } = req.body;
    const doc = new ProjectModel({
      title,
      tags,
      text,
      needs,
      socials,
      user: req.userId,
    });

    const project = await doc.save();

    await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.userId,
      { $push: { projects: project._id } },
      { new: true }
    );

    res.json(project);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "Не удалось создать статью",
    });
  }
};
```

The question is - is it possible to somehow automate the addition of projects to the user, so that after creating a project, the project created by him is automatically added to the user; if not, then why refer to another model? I apologize in advance if the question is too stupid, I just don’t understand it a little, reading the documentation didn’t make it clearer.

Comment: The relationship between two entities - the user and the project. Reference: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/data-modeling/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually quite common when working with databases and relationships between models. In your case, you're already using a reference to connect a user to their projects, which is a good approach.

Regarding automating the addition of projects to the user after creating a project, the method you're using (**findByIdAndUpdate**) is a good way to handle this relationship. However, there's an alternative method called middleware (specifically Mongoose middleware) that could help automate this process for you.

Mongoose middleware allows you to define functions that execute before or after certain operations are performed. In your case, you might consider using middleware to automatically update the user's projects array whenever a new project is created.

This an example of how you could set up middleware in your Mongoose models:

```js
// In your ProjectSchema here

// Define a pre-save middleware to automatically add the project to the user's projects array
projectSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  const project = this;
  try {
    // Find the user associated with the project and update their projects array
    await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      project.user,
      { $push: { projects: project._id } },
      { new: true }
    );
    next(); // Continue saving the project after updating the user
  } catch (err) {
    next(err); // Pass any errors to the next middleware
  }
});

// anything else you want to do
```

This middleware function (pre(**save**)) will trigger just before saving a new project to the database. It automatically finds the associated user and updates their projects array by adding the ID of the newly created project.

With this setup, every time you create a new project using ProjectModel, the middleware will automatically update the corresponding user's projects array without needing to manually update it in your create function.

Remember to import and include this middleware within your ProjectModel file for it to take effect.

However, always test thoroughly when working with such automated processes to ensure they behave as expected in all scenarios. Let me know if this is truly what you want

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer, this is exactly what I was looking for.